# .png file to Sprite(2D and UI) - still not visible under source image

Tags: unity

I am trying to use an image as a UI Image but even after changing its texture type to Sprite(2D and UI), it isn't visible in the source image menu. The file was created in MS Paint and I'm accessing the source image menu via the "circle selector" next to Source Image in the Inspector. I'm pretty sure I've never had this issue before. I wish I could share more details but there's nothing much to say. What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, I had to select a sprite mode as well. By default, the field was blank.